# Starting an application on the server using php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, linux, webserver

I have web server that publishes a web page with an image viewer and a "Start Acquisition" button.

On the server, I have a small application that looks like this: `./cgi-bin/ccss -d GenericUSBCamera ...` with several more parameters. My application belongs to *root / root*.

In the web page, I use AJAX to start the app. Here is a snippet of the code for the `onclick` associated with the button:

```
<script>
function startCapture()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open( "GET", "cgi-bin/start-capture.php?t=" + new Date().getTime(), true );
    xmlhttp.send()
}
</script>
```

Once the `send()` is done, I assume a message is sent to the server and the `start-capture.php` script is launched. Actually, it is because if I tweak the above JavaScript function and I modify `start-capture.php` to send back a `echo` I receive it correctly.

But the actual `start-capture.php` is:

```
<?php
exec( '/var/www/cgi-bin/ccss -d GenericUSBCamera...' );
?>
```

and nothing happens when we click the button. But I know the script is lauchned because if I get the return message in my JavaScript function, it is correct. But, as I said, my application `ccss` doesn't do anything. Actually it is supposed to grab from a USB camera and save images in the folder /var/www/images. Notice that all scripts/applications on server have all rights to execute and even when I start the app by hand on the server, everything is fine.

What I would like to do is what should I do to start such an application with parameters with PHP? I'm new to PHP and I'm a little confused with `exec()`, `shell_exec()`, etc...

Somebody has an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: typo? `"cgi-bin/start-capture.pho?t="`  What does firebug/devconsole say?

Comment: typo. `start-capture.php?...`. FMI, what is "firebug/devconsole"? Thanks.

Comment: Firebug is a firefox extension that lets you see network/ajax calls (headers and data), and their response headers and data.  Developer tools is for chrome that does the same thing.

Comment: Well, the application starts and send banner line to stdout (then to browser via php) but it tries to initialize a USB webcam then save pictures and I believe it doesn't have rights to do that. Is it possible? What should I do to provide Apache the good rights?

Comment: I moved the topics to another question. [Accessing USB Webcam via a PHP Script on Linux-Apache][1]. Thanks everybody!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234449/accessing-usb-webcam-via-a-php-script-on-linux-apache