# Accessing USB webcam via a PHP script on Linux/Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, webserver, userid

I want to use a USB webcam (in a small C++/OpenCV application) and call it from a PHP script. My test app looks like this:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    cv::VideoCapture C( 0 );

    cout << "C.isOpened() = " << boolalpha << C.isOpened() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The PHP script looks like this:

```
<?php
exec( escapeshellcmd( '/thepath/theapp' ), $output, $result );

var_dump( $output );
?>
```

When I call this app directly from the command line, it returns **true**.

When I call the app via php like this `php -f /the_php_script.php` it returns **true**.

When I call the app via php called by AJAX from a html file (with a button), it passes through Apache and then returns **false**.

So, my app works fine. My php script works fine too. But there is a permission or something like this that prevents php, via Apache to access the webcam (to initialize it with OpenCV library), *but the permission is sufficient to allow the app to run*.

Could someone help me? Any idea?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT 1:**

Following a suggestion, I tried to used a php script to start my app without the use of AJAX. I obtained the same results, i.e. OpenCV *cannot* initialized the USB webcam on the server.

Comment: Can you examine that without the usage of AJAX?

Comment: What do you mean? I need a AJAX request to start the php script, no?

Comment: You don't really have to user AJAX to call a PHP script, for now try to call the script without AJAX, a normal HTTP call and see what you get

Comment: PHP on the cli runs as a different user to PHP run through Apache. You need to check that the user www-data (or whatever Apache runs as on your system) has permission to run your program. I suspect that it doesn't.

Comment: Could be. On my computer, I found a **groupid** named *www-data*, not a **userid**. Also, my program runs but cannot access the USB camera. I suspect that users must belong to a given group to use the USB camera. I guess I do belong to this group but apache doesn't. Is it possible?

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash : see my **EDIT 1**, I tried to use php without AJAX and I got the same resultst.

Comment: I think that this might be a permission issue or something related to it, in order to make sure of that i would advice you to do the following procedure (without AJAX):

1) In your PHP script, at the first 2 lines write error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);

2) After executing the script check the error and access logs for your web server.

Please share what you get.

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash I closed the bug on my own side but I keep in mind your suggestion. I'll use this procedure when I'll have another problem with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those whom may be interested by the problem...

The problem I was facing was two-fold: initializing the USB webcam via a php script called from the client and starting an application *from this php script* that could write images to disk in the folder `/var/www/images`.

1. To enable the USB camera, I just had to add the user *www-data* (Apache) to the group *video*. I found it by looking at my own account: I saw that I was a member of this group so it seemed natural to add Apache to it too!
2. To allows the application (that captures images from the camera) to store them in the folder `/var/www/images` I observed that the subfolder `images` belonged to user *root* and was a member of group *root*. Since it was Apache that ran the php script that called my application, I switched the owner of `images` to *www-data*.

As we say in French... *Voilà*!

Thanks to all of you who gave me some hints!